# Error de commit en GitHub Desktop

Tags: github

me sale el siguiente error al tratar de subir mi repositorio a GitHub
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que podría hacer?
Ya renombré la rama principal, eliminando la master, dejando únicamente la rama main...
Re-hice el proyecto en nueva carpeta, y también sale lo mismo
Muchas gracias desde ya

Comment: Dice que está al día y no hay cambios para subir

Comment: Tienes que seleccionar los archivos que quieres cargar.